# Generate dictionary file from Stata data

Tags: stata

I know that I can create a `dta` file if I have `dat` file and dictionary `dct` file. However, I want to know whether the reverse is also possible. In particular, if I have a `dta` file, is it possible to generate `dct` file along with `dat` file (Stata has an `export` command that allows export as ASCII file but I haven't found a way to generate `dct` file). StatTransfer does generate `dct` and `dat` file, but I was wondering if it is possible without using StatTransfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `outfile` will create dictionaries as well as export data in ASCII (text) form.

If you want dictionaries and dictionaries alone, you would need to delete the data part.

If you really want two separate files, you would need to split each file produced by `outfile`.

Either is programmable in Stata, or you could just use your favourite text editor or scripting language.

Dictionaries are in some ways a very good idea, but they are not as important to Stata as they were in early versions.